# Unable to move uploaded file - Drupal

Tags: php, file, drupal

So a client of mine recently was asking me about an issue where they cannot upload any files using Drupal.

The error they get is (and I have now reproduced it - I changed site name to preserve privacy):

> warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move '/tmp/phpwmxeOQ' to 'sites/domain.org/files/Leading_Indicators_5.pdf' in /home/isp/domain-domains/domain.org/includes/file.inc on line 629.
>       File upload error. Could not move uploaded file.

What can cause this? Permissions issue? Safe mode for PHP? Something else? I've not really found much in the way of searching that leads me to anything concrete. Is it just a problem with a module? Is there any way of fixing it with code?

Comment: Could be permissions. Also, see if `'sites/domain.org/files/Leading_Indicators_5.pdf'` is a valid path. I guess it should be a relative path.

Comment: Permissions are set to 777 (at least for testing). /sites/domain.org/files is a valid path.

Comment: ..but you are giving `sites/domain.org/files...` and not `/sites/domain.org/files...`. The starting slash.

Comment: Thought you might be commenting on that. Hrm, I'm not sure how to fix that in Drupal.

Comment: Pretty sure it is hitting the right directory, because it is trying to upload the next sequential file - I'm putting Leading_Indicators.pdf up, and it is assigning it 5, and now 6 (once I got a successful _5 up there - the error is intermittent).

Comment: Wierd..can you turn on error_reporting and display_errors and see what gives.

Comment: This is a live site, so I'd prefer not to do that.